# Remove decimal point from N function

Tags: output-formatting

For aesthetic reasons I want to remove the decimal point when I use the function `N`. For example when put in `N[30]` I get out `30.` when I just want `30` without the decimal point. Is it possible to remove the decimal point when it is not in need?

Comment: Look at Round[].

Comment: Thanks, that solved it in this case :)

Comment: What's the point of having no point in floating point numbers? Note that with `Round` you get also `30` from `Round[N[29.999]]`,

Comment: Or use `n = 30.; IntegerPart[n]` gives `30` and the decimal is gone. Magic.

Comment: Why do you want to use `N` anyway? Why not just write `30`?